Uploading image to S3 from user-submitted form completes but corrupted
In a Remix app, I have a form I'm using to select & upload an image, just a simple <input name="image" type="file" />
The form POSTs to a Remix handler, and in the handler (see code below) I'm trying to upload this image to Amazon S3 using the v3 SDK. I've tried with both the PutObjectCommand from client-s3 and with Upload from lib-storage - same result...
The upload "works" - It successfully creates the file in the bucket. I can see the filesize matches exactly what I expect when I upload the same file directly into the S3 bucket via the web UI.
However as an "image" the file doesn't open - when I view the uploaded image from the S3 bucket the browser renders the standard "broken image icon" (similar issue if I download the image and try to open in Preview on OSX) - I have no other information about what's wrong. Something seems to be either corrupted, or created in a way that the file is not recognized as an image.

In the handler, I get the file data as an AsyncIterable<Uint8Array> and the only real processing I'm doing is to convert that into a single Uint8Array for the Upload (and have already tried setting the body to a buffer and a blob, same result).
Is there something wrong with my conversion to a Uint8Array or is there a more correct way to convert that for the upload, maybe a different type?
Or something else I need to configure in the way I'm setting the upload to S3?
async ({ name, contentType, data, filename }) => {
  const arrayOfUInt8Array: Uint8Array[] = [];

  let length = 0;
  for await (const x of data)
  {
    arrayOfUInt8Array.push(x);
    length += x.length;
  }

  const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(length);

  for (const x of arrayOfUInt8Array) {
    uInt8Array.set(x);
  }


  // Tried creating a buffer from the Uint8Array...
  const buff = Buffer.from(uInt8Array);
  // Tried creating a blob from the Uint8Array...
  const blob = new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });


  const uploadCommand = new Upload({
    client: s3Client,
    params: {
      Bucket: s3Bucket,
      Key: filename,
      Body: uInt8Array,
      ContentType: contentType,
    }
  });

  await uploadCommand.done();

  return '';
},


uInt8Array.set(x) overwrites uInt8Array from the beginning. Presumably you meant to use the .set(source, offset) variant so the second element's data is written after the first?

@Botje ahh that was exactly it, thank you

As noted by @Botje in a comment, the issue was with the construction of the Uint8Array, where the source was continually being overwritten at the beginning, and the rest of the array was empty.
So instead of:
  for (const x of arrayOfUInt8Array) {
    uInt8Array.set(x);
  }

I needed:
  let i = 0;
  let currentIndex = 0;
  for (const x of arrayOfUInt8Array) {
    uInt8Array.set(x, currentIndex)
    currentIndex += arrayOfUInt8Array[i].length
    i += 1
  }


I usually have a two-parts strategy to handle this:
1st parse the upload as NodeDiskOnFile using Remix's built in functionality:
const uploadHandler = unstable_composeUploadHandlers(
    unstable_createFileUploadHandler({
      maxPartSize: 10_000_000,
      file: ({ filename }) => filename,
    }),
    // parse everything else into memory
    unstable_createMemoryUploadHandler()
  );

const formData = await unstable_parseMultipartFormData(
    request,
    uploadHandler
  );

Then I upload the files using a presigned URL:
for (const file of files) {
    const uploadedURL = await uploadFileWithPresignedUrl(file);
    dataWithAWSUrls.uploadedFiles.push(uploadedURL);
  }

Here's how the presignedUrl functions are structured:
import {
  GetObjectCommand,
  PutObjectCommand,
  S3Client,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { NodeOnDiskFile } from "@remix-run/node";
import axios from "axios";

import slugify from "slugify";
import { slugifyOptions } from "~/constants/constants";
import { env } from "~/env";

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: env.AWS_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
});

async function streamToBuffer(
  readable: ReadableStream<Uint8Array>
): Promise<Buffer> {
  const data: Uint8Array[] = [];
  const reader = readable.getReader();

  try {
    while (true) {
      const { value, done } = await reader.read();
      if (done) break;
      data.push(value);
    }
  } finally {
    reader.releaseLock();
  }

  return Buffer.concat(data.map((chunk) => Buffer.from(chunk)));
}

export async function uploadFileWithPresignedUrl(file: File | NodeOnDiskFile) {
  const buffer = await streamToBuffer(file.stream());

  const slugifiedFileName = slugify(file.name, slugifyOptions);

  const command: any = new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: slugifiedFileName,
    Body: buffer,
    ContentType: file.type,
  });

  const url = await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });

  // Upload file with presigned url
  await axios.put(url, buffer, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": file.type,
      "Content-Length": buffer.length,
    },
  });

  const publicUrl = `https://${env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/${slugifiedFileName}`;

  // Return the url of the uploaded file
  return publicUrl;
}

export async function getFileWithPresignedUrl(key: string) {
  const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: key,
  });
  const signedUrl = getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
  return signedUrl;
}

